# WebDriver issue - sendKeys() losing focus / posting in wrong order

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am in the process of moving my home server to a Linode box. After the transition, my WebDriver script has begun acting a little weird.

Both servers are running Ubuntu 16.04 with identical versions of selenium.

However I am running chrome 65 on the new box and 58 on the old.

The issue...
When entering text from MySQL into the description field on the site, if there are no html tags being inserted, everything seems to work as intended. However, if html tags are included, the description field is in the incorrect order.

From watching it run, it looks like the text is being “typed in the correct order, but the cursor will randomly just to the beginning/middle/end of the text field, causing the final field to be in a strange order.

** each iteration of the code produces the text in the same (incorrect) order
** the same results occur whether I am currently Interacting with the machine or not

Comment: Having the exact same issues. We partially solved it by using sendKeys, and then checking if that value was entered correctly. If it wasn't, we would type it out one character at a time. This still didn't work for some reason in some cases.. not sure why.